# jQuery count contents of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, keyup

I have a system this counts how many textboxes in the class "Today" have the value "/". I want this to also count if it has the value "L" or "l". I have tried the following:

```
$('.today').keyup(function() {
    var Presents = $('input:visible').filter(function(){
      return this.value == "/";  
    });
    $("#counter").html( "Present: " + Presents.length );
});
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var Presents = $('input:visible').filter(function(){
      return this.value == "/";  
    });
    $("#counter").html( "Present: " + Presents.length );
});
```

I have tried the following solution:

```
return this.value == "/", "l", "L";
```

This resulted in all of the text boxes being counted, whatever the value.

Comment: I'm actually going to give you a `+1` for using `this.value` instead of constructing a whole jQuery object (`$(this).val()`) just to get a basic property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest answer here is probably regex:

```
return /^[\/lL]$/.test(this.value);
```

(This checks for a single-char string where the char is one of `/`, `i`, or `L`.)

More generally, your choices here are essentially:

- An OR'd series of conditionals: `val === "/" || val === "i" || val === "L"`. This is clear, but redundant, and stops being legible after about three options. It's worth noting, however, that this is probably the fastest option - this might matter if you had to test 10k strings in quick succession.
- A regex check as above. This is likely the most concise code, and it's easy to add more characters or more complex patterns to the check, but it's less legible.
- Array inclusion. This is easiest when you have access to modern array methods, e.g. `return chars.any(function(c) { return c === val; })`. This may be the best option if your list of search strings is determined at runtime, or simply if it's very long.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your code is identical to `return "L"`, which is truthy, so all inputs are returned.

Did you mean:

```
return this.value == "/" || this.value == "l" || this.value == "L";
```

If so, you could also use:

```
return this.value.length == 1 && "/lL".indexOf(this.value)+1;
```

Might not seem like much of a savings, but allows you to define your list of characters much more easily, in case you want to add more in future.

Answer (score 1):

try: `return this.value.match(/[\/li]/) !== null`

Comment: `.match` returns `null` on failure, so this is going to throw an error on misses.

Comment: Eh just check for null then same difference. Updated reference to reflect the change.